# Creating and stopping threads from listview

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need your help, with threads I'm full 0 and you only need to create a certain thread and complete it on command, BUT I do not create each thread in advance, as there will be a lot of them, I do it like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => Go(..... many many variables that are taken from the listview ......));
thread.Start();
```

So, as noted above, variables are taken from the listview, which in turn is loaded by me from the file and then I run the threads I need. BUT the process in the stream is infinite and will end only if I completely close the program, and I would like to end the stream in the same way as I started it (right click on the desired line-start/stop). As I said, I have never worked with threads and thought that it was somehow simple, like when you start a thread, you assign it an ID and end it with the same ID, but alas. I have searched all over Google and have not found an EXAMPLE that suits me (I will repeat for the third time - I have never worked with threads and I do not need to say "go read about TPL"), so I ask for help, preferably with an example)

I have a very bad idea: in the sheet there is an invisible column in which an id is generated at the start, then when I send a command to start the thread, a unique variable is created with the name for example int id1=0 and its name is passed to the thread itself and each time the loop starts, id1=0 or 1 is checked in it, respectively, if 0-continue, if 1-empty. Well, it is logical that when you click the stop button, its value changes to 1. But something seems to me that the holy spirit of multithreading will punish me for this when the threads become 100+. I read this idea somewhere, so don't swear)

Comment: In modern c#, you should probably not be working directly with threads (unless you are a pretty advanced developer and have a compelling reason).  There are many other language features for handling multiple tasks, such as `async Task`, TPL, and `BackgroundWorker`. I suggest you describe the larger problem you are trying to solve and someone can probably provide a simple way to do it.

Comment: Well, look, I have a program that loads a list of accounts (there can be 5, 10 or 100, that is, I do not know the number of threads in advance). All accounts are loaded into the listview and from there, using the context menu, run in an endless stream that executes http commands. Everything works fine in my opinion, but the problem is that I can only complete the execution by closing the program completely, and I would like to close each account separately if necessary, and I can't imagine how to do this from the same context menu.

Comment: With the launch, everything is clear, the data from the strings is passed to the stream and passed to the method at startup, and if it were possible to assign each thread some unique identifier and terminate the necessary thread with this id, then everything would be fine. I don't need to sync them with each other and so on, just start/stop each thread individually)

Comment: You should probably consider using Tasks and CancellationTokens. Also, there are women here.

Comment: @TonyPak - In modern C# you cannot stop a thread. You have to have the thread's cooperation to end. The only way around that is to run your new thread in a separate process and kill the process, and that's messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need hundreds of threads for this. Your worker "threads" are performing HTTP requests, which can be done asynchronously without requiring a new thread. Also, hundreds of threads wouldn't really help you unless you have hundreds of CPU cores (you don't).

For this sort of work, I'd recommend the following:

1. Write a method that does all the work your thread does, but also checks a `CancellationToken` with each iteration.
2. Calls the method in a loop, once for each account, and store the resulting tasks in an array or list. Or use LINQ (as I do in this example) to create the list.
3. When your program terminates, activate the `CancellationToken`.
4. After cancelling, you have to `await` all the tasks in order to observe any possible exceptions and exit cleanly.

For example

```
public async Task DoTheWork(Account account, CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(account.Url);
        await DoSomethingWithResult(result);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}

//Main program
var accounts = GetAccountList();
var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
var tasks = accounts.Select( x => DoTheWork(x, source.Token) ).ToList();


//When exiting
source.Cancel();
await Task.WhenAll( tasks );
source.Dispose();
```

### Indivivdual cancellation

Here's another approach that keeps a list of the accounts and a delegate that can be used for cancelling the task for that specific account.

```
//Declare this somewhere it will persist for the duration of the program
//The key to this dictionary is the account you wish to cancel
//The value is a delegate that you can call to cancel its task
Dictionary<Account, Func<Task>> _tasks = new Dictionary<Account, Func<Task>>();

async Task CreateTasks()
{
    var accounts = GetAccounts();
    foreach (var account in accounts)
    {
        var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = DoTheWork(account, source.Token);
        _tasks.Add(account, () => { source.Cancel(); return task; });
    }
}

//Retrieve the delegate from the dictionary and call it to cancel its task
//Then await the task to observe any exceptions
//Then remove it from the list
async Task CancelTask(Account account)
{
    var cancelAction = _tasks[account];
    var task = cancelAction();
    await task;
    _tasks.Remove(account);
}

async Task CancelAllTasks()
{
    var tasks = _tasks.Select(x => x.Value()).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the hint, but how will this help me in stopping a particular account if necessary? Stop it manually, and not when some condition is met.

Comment: As I understand it, your example will help me to start and stop all the tasks at once? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: You might create one CancellationTokenSource per account.

Comment: @TonyPak There's several ways to do it-- see my edited answer for one way. This approach is a little "clever" because it uses captured variables instead of declaring a proper data structure. Let me know if it's too confusing and I can show you a way without using a delegate.

Comment: @JohnWu I will try to understand if I write something, thank you very much!